# Why am I getting this error? Encountered the symbol "SQLSTATE" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

Tags: mysql, triggers

Write a trigger to ensure that no employee of age less than 25 can be inserted in the database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ?Check_age 
BEFORE INSERT ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF NEW.age < 25 THEN 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR: AGE MUST BE ATLEAST 25 YEARS!'; 
        END IF; 
    END;
```

Comment: I tested this trigger in MySQL 5.7.34 (after removing the "?" character) and I get no error. I think you are getting an error in some different code.

Comment: The formatting of the question needs to be improved.